# hadoop 2.2.0 Exception from container-launch at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Tags: hadoop, configuration

I'm new to Hadoop and trying to set hadoop 2.2.0 on a server with 32-cores & 64GB mem & 8 disks, while I tweaked around with the files 'yarn-site.xml', I found that when I add

```
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
<value>40960</value>
</property>
```

to 'yarn-site.xml' and run:

```
hadoop jar ./share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar pi 10 5
```

I get the error:

```
14/01/23 19:42:55 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1390524052844_0002_m_000002_0, Status : FAILED
Exception from container-launch:
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException:
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:464)
...
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

but the task will be completed anyway, but if I run

```
hadoop jar ./share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar pi 20 5
```

There will be so many such errors that the task would stop there and would never finish.

But if I remove that property from 'yarn-site.xml', every thing will work fine. However I need to set this property cause the default value is 8192MB and I want to make full use of the mem.

Can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that it was the max processes num is limited to 1024, I set it to 13172, it finally works now. If you are running hadoop on a single linux server and want to work with it, be sure to check this setting.

Been troubled by this for a week, hope this post can help someone else.

BTW, use 'ulimit -a' to see the limits in linux

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this error too, but solved it by checking `$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml`. At last I found that the `mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address` was set to a wrong value.